# MSBuild deploying a referenced project

Tags: msbuild, azure-webjobs, msdeploy

I have a solution with many webjobs. One webjob references another and when I attempt to deploy with MSBuild, it tries to deploy the dependent project. Any special magic to tell it to only deploy the main project instead of any referenced projects as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the reference of other WebJob .exe file. And then deploy it, it will only deploy the single WebJob with the webjob assembly.

Choose add reference then browse the webjob .exe file.

[image]

Then the solution would be like this:

[image]

And in the Kudu, it will deploy the .exe and config file.

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other question,please let me know.

Comment: I'd rather not move away from a project reference to an assembly reference. Can you explain what the difference is between what VS is doing and what MSBuild is doing that causes the difference in deployment?